# Getting Selected DropDownButton Value from Child Widget

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm currently building a screen in Flutter where I have a main parent widget that uses a child widget. The child widget contains 2 Textfields and a DropDownButton. I have a weird situation where my '**selectedUserValue**' value for the DropDownButton isn't being updated correctly. Whenever I do a print("$selectedUserValue entered") it always return 0, but it seems to be working in the child widget? Does anyone why it works in the child but not in the Parent?

Code is below:

**Parent Widget**

```
class VisitorScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  List<User> activeUsers = [];

  TextEditingController firstNameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController lastNameController = TextEditingController();
  int selectedUserValue = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title:
                Image.asset("images/test.png", fit: BoxFit.cover),
            backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(246, 248, 250, 1.0)),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Flexible(
                child: VisitorInputControl(firstNameController,
                    lastNameController, selectedUserValue)),
            Flexible(
                child: Center(child: ElevatedButton(
              child: Text("Next"),
              onPressed: validateUser,
            )))
          ],
        ));
  }

  void validateUser() {

    print("$selectedUserValue entered");

  }
}
```

**Child Widget**

```
class VisitorInputControl extends StatefulWidget {

  TextEditingController firstNameController;
  TextEditingController lastNameController;
  int selectedUserID;

  VisitorInputControl(this.firstNameController, this.lastNameController, this.selectedUserID);

  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return VisitorInputControlState();
  }

}

class VisitorInputControlState extends State<VisitorInputControl> {
  
  List<User> activeUsers = [];

  @override
  initState() {

    super.initState();

    _getActiveUserList();

  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double textFieldWidth = 400;

    List<DropdownMenuItem> dropdownMenu = [];
    dropdownMenu.add(DropdownMenuItem(child: Text(""), value: 0,));

    for (int i = 0; i < activeUsers.length; i++) {
      DropdownMenuItem item = DropdownMenuItem(
          child: Text("${activeUsers[i].firstName} ${activeUsers[i].lastName}"),
          value: activeUsers[i].id);
      dropdownMenu.add(item);
    }

    DropdownButton activeUsersDropdown = DropdownButton(
        hint: new Text("Visiting Staff"),
        isExpanded: true,
        items: dropdownMenu,
        value: widget.selectedUserID,
        onChanged: (value) { 
          dropdownCallback(value);
        });

    return Center(
        child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
      Flexible(
          child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 10.0, right: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
              width: textFieldWidth,
              child: TextField(
                controller: widget.firstNameController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                //border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'First Name',
              )))),
      Flexible(
          child: Container(
              width: textFieldWidth,
              child: TextField(
                controller: widget.lastNameController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Last Name',
              )))),
      Flexible(
          child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
              width: textFieldWidth,
              child: activeUsersDropdown))
    ]));
  }

  void _getActiveUserList() async {
  
    UserApi api = UserApi();

    List<dynamic> usersFuture = await api.getActiveUser();

    _addUsersToList(usersFuture);

  }

  void _addUsersToList(List<dynamic> userList)
  {

    setState(() {
      for (int i = 0; i < userList.length; i++){

      Map<String, dynamic> currentUserMap = userList[i];
      User currentUser = User.fromJson(currentUserMap);

      activeUsers.add(currentUser);

      }
    });

  }

  void dropdownCallback(int selectedValue) {

      setState(() {
        widget.selectedUserID = selectedValue;
      });

  }

  void _displayError() {
    print("failed to retrieve users");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess because the parent widget is a stateless widget. Have you tried it as an stateful widget?

Comment: From what I understand, it shouldn't matter whether the parent is stateful or not because the child is stateful and are setting the state of the variable from there. However, I have tried your suggestion and can confirm it still doesn't work after changing it from stateless to stateful. Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your problem. You are not returning any value from the child to the parent in the code provided. And if you did, without a stateful widget you would not see any change anyways, because the parent would not be re-rendered, only the child